# Why does gcc warn "assuming signed overflow" in one case and not in the other

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings, integer-overflow

Consider the following code:

```
$ cat o.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int absolute(int i) {
  int j = i < 0 ? -i : i;
  if (j<0)      /* This is line 6 */
    return 0;
  return j;
}

int main() {
  int i = 1;
  printf("%d %d\n", i, absolute(i));
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling it with `-O2` and `-Wstrict-overflow` produces a warning:

```
$ gcc -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wstrict-overflow o.c 
o.c: In function ‘absolute’:
o.c:6:6: warning: assuming signed overflow does not occur when simplifying comparison of absolute value and zero [-Wstrict-overflow]
```

Now consider the following which seems functionally equivalent to the above code:

```
$ cat p.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {
  int i = 1;
  int j = i < 0 ? -i : i;
  if (j<0) // Changing i to INT_MIN above and changing (j<0) to (j>INT_MAX)
           // doesn't change the behavior
    j=0;
  printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling this with the same options doesn't result in any warnings.

```
$ gcc -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wstrict-overflow p.c 
$
```

As commented in the second code, changing the assignment to `i=INT_MIN;` and the condition to `(j>INT_MAX)` doesn't warn either.

I'm using gcc 4.7.2 on Ubuntu:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2
```

I'm unable to figure the difference in the two cases.  Does it have something to do with optimization or is gcc not behaving quite right here?

Comment: I suspect that in the second case, `j`'s value is known by the time `j<0` gets optimised, but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two snippets are different from the point of view of the compiler's intra-procedural analyses for optimization.

In the first one, GCC knows and tells you that it is going to compile function `absolute()` into something that may differ from what you expected if you believed that signed overflow always produces two's complement results (It doesn't. [Signed overflow is undefined behavior](http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/120). GCC can choose any behavior it wishes for the inputs to `absolute()` that cause signed overflow. In this case, the compiler is going to remove `if (j<0) …` as dead code, which is the correct behavior for the defined inputs)

In the second snippet, there is no such possible misunderstanding because `-i` never overflows (since `i` can be seen to be `1` with only a local value analysis). All behaviors of the function are defined, there is no cause for disagreement between GCC and the programmer, and no reason to emit a warning.

Then, there is the fact that GCC does not warn for `i=INT_MIN;`. This is probably caused by the order in which passes are applied. I would bet that a constant propagation pass has been applied first, so that a value(*) for the condition `j<0` has already been computed at the time when the sophisticated optimizing pass that emits the warning is applied. This latter pass does not see the comparison so it has no reason to warn.

If you wish signed overflow to always produce two's complement results, you can use `gcc -fwrapv -fno-strict-overflow`. Ian Lance Taylor alludes to these options in his post but he does not make it clear why a second option was necessary to really make GCC behave when there was already one that should have done this job. Using these options should make the warning “assuming signed overflow does not occur” disappear.

(*) I should insist that this is **a** value for the condition. Again, the compiler may choose any value it wants because computing `-INT_MIN` is undefined behavior on this architecture. The constant propagation pass may apply two's complement but it does not have to.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  It seems that using `-fwrapv` would suffice.  Moreover, the documentation says: `When -fwrapv is used, there is no difference between -fstrict-overflow and -fno-strict-overflow for integers.`

Comment: In addition to Ian Lance Taylor's blog referenced by you, [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49820#c7) comment from a GCC bug report also contains helpful information about the compiler flags you mentioned.

Comment: The difference between `-fno-strict-overflow` and `-fwrapv` is mostly conceptual, as far as I can tell: the former instructs the compiler to not assume that overflow does not take place (the compiler may figure out that `j < 0` is never true, but may not make use of that fact), the latter redefines the arithmetic operations so that overflow is impossible (the compiler knows that `j < 0` is a real possibility). If you really *want* `-INT_MIN` to have a guaranteed result, I think you should use `-fwrapv` (and `-f(no-)strict-overflow` is ignored in that case), not just `-fno-strict-overflow`.

Comment: -fwrapv instructs the compiler that integer overflow wraps. -fno-strict-overflow just tells the compiler that integer overflow can happen, but not what happens when it does (basically, insert / remove no special code). If your processor has saturating arithmetic (so INT_MAX + 1 == INT_MAX), that is probably what would happen.

Comment: @hvd: The difference isn't just conceptual.  Given `-fno-strict-overflow` but not `-fwrapv`, code like `int m=INT_MAX; long long L=m+1;` might arbitrarily set `L` to `INT_MAX+1L`, `-INT_MAX-1`, or possibly some other values, but would not negate the laws of time and causality.  Without `-fno-strict-overflow`, anything could happen.

Answer (score 2):

In the first program the optimizer recognizes the sign of an absolute value is checked with a variable argument not known at compile time.

In the second program, the value of `i` is known and the result of `j` and `j < 0` are computed at compile time *before* any further optimizations like the one used in the first program.

A good way to get convinced of this is to change the value of `i` in the second program to something known only at run-time:

```
int i = 1 + printf(""); // 1 if no error, cannot be deduced
                        // at compile time
int j = i < 0 ? -i : i;
if (j<0)
```

would get you the same warning as in the first program when compiled with `-O2   -Wstrict-overflow`.

Comment: Thanks, it explains the warning in the former case.